# Using the naive Bayes function on a test and training set of data

Tags: r, naivebayes

I am trying to use the NaiveBayes function on a training and test set of data. I am using this helpful website: https://rpubs.com/riazakhan94/naive_bayes_classifier_e1071

However, for some reason it is not working and this is error that I am getting:" Error in table(train$Class, trainPred) : all arguments must have the same length. "

Here is the code that I am using, I am guessing its a super simple fix. The x and y columns of the data set are predicting on the class column:

https://github.com/samuelc12359/NaiveBayes.git

```
test <- read.csv(file="TestX.csv",header=FALSE)
train <- read.csv(file="TrainX.csv",header=FALSE)

Names <- c("x","y","Class")
colnames(test)<- Names
colnames(train)<- Names

NBclassfier=naiveBayes(Class~x+y, data=train)
print(NBclassfier)


trainPred=predict(NBclassfier,train, type="class")
trainTable=table(train$Class, trainPred)
testPred=predict(NBclassfier, newdata=test, type="class")
testTable=table(test$Class, testPred)
print(trainTable)
print(testTable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn the `Class` column into factors, e.g. like this:

```
train$Class = factor(train$Class)
test$Class = factor(test$Class)
```

Then when you call `naiveBayes()` to train, and later to predict, it will do what you expect.

Alternatively, you can change prediction type to `"raw"` and turn them into outcomes directly. E.g. like this:

```
train_predictions = predict(NBclassfier,train, type="raw")
trainPred = 1 * (train_predictions[, 2] >= 0.5 )
trainTable=table(train$Class, trainPred)
test_predictions = predict(NBclassfier, newdata=test, type="raw")
testPred = 1 * (test_predictions[, 2] >= 0.5 )
testTable=table(test$Class, testPred)
print(trainTable)
print(testTable)
```

Comment: YOU are my favorite person on the internet thank you so much!!!!